Slower and faster responses: API rest Grails vs API Rest Springboot
I have two rest APIs, one was created using Grails 4.0.3. The other, SpringBoot. I don't know why, but the app Grails, when is just deployed and if it stays a lot of time without receiving requests, the application is slow to respond. Very slow. But after this slow response, the other request works faster.
This does not happen with SpringBoot. Regardless if the app has just deloyed, or if stays a lot of time without receiving requests, it works as expected.
Anyone know about some configuration in Grails to help it to perform like Springboot does? Could anyone please help me?
Thanks!
Alfredo

Ensure your JVM options are optimized for server-side applications. For example, setting -Xmx and -Xms appropriately based on your server's memory capabilities can help reduce startup times and improve overall performance.

Hi efsandido. Thank you for your response. I have already done this. It does not work. The applications do not need much memory. The problem happens only in the very first request. The other request have acceptable response time.

Grails is built on the SpringBoot, so it shares many underlying components and principles. However, differences in configuration defaults, plugins, or how certain components are utilized can lead to varying behavior between a Grails app and a standard SpringBoot app, especially regarding performance.
It sounds like you are facing a performance issue with your Grails app, especially when it's idle for a while. It is difficult to say what might be causing this without looking at the actual piece of code that is executed and causing issues. Here are a few things you can check/debug and try to improve the performance:

Use tools like JConsole, VisualVM, or application performance monitoring (APM) tools to monitor your application's performance metrics.
Enable debug logs to trace where the delays are occurring. This can help pinpoint whether it's related to db query, session, or other aspects of the application.
Grails might have different default configurations for certain components such as Hibernate, caching, or connection pooling compared to a typical SpringBoot setup. These defaults could impact the performance characteristics, especially under certain load or idle conditions.
Verify the SpringBoot version used in the Grails app vs the one used directly. The Grails might be using a different version of SpringBoot.
Ensure your JVM options are optimized as mentioned by @efsandino  at here

